# how can I insert text on image type input by using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert text on input image like below image

[image]

i.e. I have

```
<input id="faq" type=image" src="img_path"/>
```

and I want to put text on it using CSS.
(also I should do handle the position of text)

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: This link might help [link](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/yyOodm)

Comment: @KaoriYui thank you for comment. Im referencing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative; 
}

.text {
  position: absolute; 
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  top: calc(50% - 9px); 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="text">FAQ</div>
   <input class="imgInput" id="faq" type="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5t4o.gif">
</div>
```

This is one way to do it. This may not be exactly what you are looking for but this is one way to do it.